# Strange behavior in writeLines function

Tags: r

I am trying to write a source code, however the `writeLines` function seems to be producing a strange output.

```
cod <- 'filenam <- list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$")'
writeLines(cod, "source1.R")
```

When I try to execute the source in bash I get an error.

```
Rscript source1.R
```

> Error: '.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting
>   ""." Execution halted

Checking the sources I realized that the code lost one `\`. It was modified from `list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$")` to `list.files(pattern = "\.txt$")` when exported as a file by the `writeLines` function.

Any idea why and how deal with that?

Comment: Are you in windows or Mac? I bet windows.

Comment: Linux server, by SSH. However, I am not sure about the version...

Comment: Keep in mind your examples should be minimal.  You don't need the loop here to reproduce your issue and makes it harder for you and anybody else to debug.

Comment: Yes I understand your point @Dason. I just included the loop because it is as I am using my original code (and how it went wrong). Please feel free to modify my question if you thing that will make things clear.

Comment: I tried to simplify the question anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double escape:

```
cod <- 'filenam <- list.files(pattern = "\\\\.txt$")'
writeLines(cod, "source1.R")
```

That produces a file that looks like:

```
filenam <- list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$")
```

Sourcing that, gets your correct behavior because `\\.` resolves to `\.` for the purposes of a regular expression.

To get a sense of this, look at:

```
cat("\\.R$")
## \.R$
```